# Is there any implications on updating Azure SQL server from V11 to V12?

Tags: azure-sql-database

We are planning to update our servers but we can't be sure if there will be any implications or problems if we do that? Did anyone experienced any issue and how big they were? Or should I expect an issue or it would be updated smoothly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Azure documentation page lists the limitations during and after the upgrade:

[Plan and prepare to upgrade to SQL Database V12](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/sql-database-v12-plan-prepare-upgrade/)